# How do i hide some words in a string from a txt in php

Tags: php, text, show-hide, words

I'm new to php and have the following code to show the string there's inside a .txt file in my web:

```
<?php
$file = "file.txt";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
    print $line;
}
?>
```

I'd like to know how to select some words to be hidden. In my case I want to hide the numbers (01,02,03,04,05,1,2,3,4,5) in the line.
I also want to replace the whole line for another one in case it starts with a certain word. For example if the line starts with the word "example" replace the whole line and only display the words "hello world"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the numbers:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\d/", "", "This 1 is 01 2 a 2 test 4 45 aaa");
echo $str;
```

**Output:**
This  is   a  test   aaa

[*Link to fiddler*](http://codepad.org/xmFIaw8u)

---

To replace the the whole line (only if it starts with "example") with "hello world":

```
$str =  "example This 1 is 01 2 a 2 test 4 45 aaa";
echo preg_replace("/^example.*/", "hello world", $str);
```

**Output:**

hello world

[*Link to fiddler*](http://codepad.org/OtUmT0tz)

---

Combining both together will give us:

```
   $file = "file.txt";
   $f = fopen($file, "r");
   while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
      $line = preg_replace("/^example.*/", "hello world", $line);
      $line = preg_replace("/\d/", "", $line);
     print $line;

   }
```

Comment: i'll just select the numbers i want to be hidden. i want this kind of numbers only (001, 002, 003, 004, ...) any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. You can replace `/\d/` with `/[0-9]{3}/`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   $hideStartWith = "example";
   $replaceWith = "hello world";
   $hideText = array("01","02","03","04","05","1","2","3","4","5");

   $file = "file.txt";
   $f = fopen($file, "r");
   while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
      if(substr($line, 0, strlen($hideStartWith)) === $hideStartWith){
         $line = $replaceWith;  //print "hello world" if the line starts with "example"
     } else {
         foreach($hideText as $h)
             $line = str_replace($h, "", $line); //filtering the numbers
     }

     print $line;

   }
?>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't work :S
Thanks for the trouble! i must be doing something wrong

Comment: It has changed the numbers for the selected line...
where should i input the line i want to be replaced with?

Comment: sorry for my bad. I have updated the code, you can change the variable $replaceWith to do that.

Comment: This is actually working.. it has removed the numbers..
I still cannot achieve the line replace.. I dont know where to input the line it has to be replaced to.
!!

Answer (score 1):

for the entire line replace, try:

```
if (stripos($my_line, "example")===0){
     $my_line = "example";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: it hasn't worked. this is what i have
     
        <?php
$file = "file.txt";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
print $line;
}
if (stripos($my_line, "example")===0){
     $my_line = "hello world";
}
?>